# Swiftui load and save Encoded @Published properties

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swiftui

I took a code from Apple's tutorial:

```
class ScrumStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var scrums: [DailyScrum] = []
    
    private static func fileURL() throws -> URL {
        try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                       in: .userDomainMask,
                                       appropriateFor: nil,
                                       create: false)
            .appendingPathComponent("scrums.data")
    }
    
    static func load(completion: @escaping (Result<[DailyScrum], Error>)->Void) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            do {
                let fileURL = try fileURL()
                guard let file = try? FileHandle(forReadingFrom: fileURL) else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(.success([]))
                    }
                    return
                }
                let dailyScrums = try JSONDecoder().decode([DailyScrum].self, from: file.availableData)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.success(dailyScrums))
                }
            } catch {
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    static func save(scrums: [DailyScrum], completion: @escaping (Result<Int, Error>)->Void) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            do {
                }
            } catch {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I have 3 @Published properties:

```
@Published var events: [Event]
@Published var contacts: [Contact]
@Published var services: [Service]
```

can I make a dictionary something like

var data: (events: [Event], contacts: [Contact], services: [Service])

and make **for in** function to load and save all the Published properties that I add to data dictionary?

Comment: What you are suggesting isn't a dictionary. It just looks like a `struct`. You wouldn't use `for in` to load the data. Is there something specific you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to have one nice function to load and save data, so that there's a struct, where I just put one more @Published var and the array of Objects and the function then takes the name like events.data and encodes and decoded [Event] and so on...